# Altering table on SQL Server 2012 AON High Availability Databases

Tags: sql-server-2012, high-availability

In a production site, the current configuration I am using is three SQL Server 2012 servers, with some databases configured with AON High Availability. I understand that between the AON High Availability databases, data would be replicated, but I was wondering if this remains true for the table definition. By my understanding, I believe that table structures not to be handled manually. CMIIW.

Assuming that is correct, what is the best way for me to deploy changes in table structure with minimal downtime?

Update:

It seems I missed out a similar question but with different wording, but nevertheless it answers my question: [Do schema changes "break" SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn or are they handled transparently?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21404/do-schema-changes-break-sql-server-2012-alwayson-or-are-they-handled-transpare?rq=1)

Even though it's a duplicate question, but I think I'll keep this just for those who is searching it with a different wordings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that changes in table structure (schema) is automatically handled, so changes in the primary database should be also reflected in the secondary ones.

> Schema changes and data changes are essentially the same. It works like traditional mirroring today : what happened in the log on the primary happens on the secondary. Not everything that happens in Vegas has to stay in Vegas. :-)

Source: [Do schema changes "break" SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn or are they handled transparently?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21404/do-schema-changes-break-sql-server-2012-alwayson-or-are-they-handled-transpare?rq=1)